# Stuck in Infinite loop, why it does not wait for scanner to re-enter the values

Tags: java, loops, oop, exception, do-while

i have this code of a method which i call from the main class after making this class object, once i give it an incorrect input, it does not ask for to re-enter the value (wait for scanner) despite it becomes an infinite loop.
won't the do-while re-run the try block or there's some logical error in the code ?

```
 public void setArrayID() {
    boolean validInput = false;
    do {
      System.out.print("Array ID: ");
      try {
        arrayID = scanner.nextInt();
        validInput = true;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        validInput = false;
        System.out.println("You must enter an ID (decimal numbers only)\nPlease Try Again !");
      }
    } while (!validInput);
    System.out.println("ID has been set to: " + arrayID);
  }
```

Comment: You have to call `next()` within the loop to clear the bad input

Comment: thanks @GBlodgett solved :)

Comment: No problem. Happy coding!